# c# referencing my calculation instead of just taking its value when assigning a float

Tags: c#

This is what I have:

```
        float f1 = 1;
        float f5 = 10;
        float fout = f1 * 2;
        while (f1 * 2 < f5)
        {
            f1++;
        }
```

The float "fout" has the value the simple calculation of "f1 * 2"
In my project that calculation is more complicated and uses about 4 local variables.
In the above example I have to type in the same calculation twice: "f1 * 2" which is what I'm trying to avoid.

I am aware I could do it using a function:

```
        float f1 = 1;
        float f5 = 10;
        float fout = calc(f1);
        while (calc(f1) < f5)
        {
            f1++;
        }

        FUNCTION:
        float calc(float inn)
        {
            return inn * 2;
        }
```

But that will also look quiet ugly since I'll have to pass 4 local variables to the function in my real project and will end up creating a large amount of small functions only used twice.

But can I do it like this?

```
        float f1 = 1;
        float f5 = 10;
        float fout = ref (f1 * 2);
        while (fout < f5)
        {
            f1++;
        }
```

Making "fout" referencing my calculation instead of just taking its value as it is assigned. If so what is the correct syntax?

EDIT:
Thank you to: Spook and undermind.
This is what I was looking for:

```
        float f1 = 1;
        float f5 = 10;
        Func<float> fout = () => f1 * 2;
        while (fout() < f5)
        {
            f1++;
        }
```

Comment: Please try to clarify in the title and the body of the question what you are asking. Both options seem correct, what are you actually asking: Which is more memory efficient? Which is faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you may simply use a lambda. Eh, the lack of subfunctions in C-style languages...

```
float f1 = 1;
float f5 = 10;
Func<float> fout = () => f1 * 2;
while (fout() < f5)
{
    f1++;
}
```

Alternatively (depending on your needs):

```
float f1 = 1;
float f5 = 10;
Func<float, float> fout = (param) => param * 2;
while (fout(f1) < f5)
{
    f1++;
}
```

All local variables are accessible automatically.

Comment: `var fout = () => f1 * 2;` results in the "Cannot assign lambda expression to an implicitly-typed local variable" error. Shouldn't we use `Func<float> fout` and get a result calling `fout.Invoke()`?

Comment: @undermind Half of it :) Type has to be explicitly set, but you can call it simply using () operator.